# How does Spring Authentication work?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-security

I've been trying to make a web service that receives a username and password and returns some sort of session that tells the receiver what they can and cannot do.

1. Where and how does Spring handle sessions and permissions?
2. On my login form I have

`<form method="POST" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"
    />">`

What does this do and is it possible to create a web service that does the same thing?

Comment: springsecurity documentation should give you a general idea have you seen the docs at http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your project is integrated with spring-security plugin. `<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check">` --This line submit userid,paswd to spring security interceptor which in turn decide to call service or do whatever as mentioned in spring-security.xml file. check for following code in your web.xml file for confirmation..

```
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Post your spring configuration.xml file and web.xml for more analysis. For authentication why you want to write webservice? For more information on spring security read the doc http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think my weak point in understanding is mainly on the web service side though. I need to write it in a web service so that 3rd parties can connect to a URL and receive raw data (like a wsdl) but if they aren't permitted to access that data then the wsdl or what ever I use should return some sort of error... In my spring-security.xml I have `<form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/admin/index"
            authentication-failure-url="/index?error=true"
            />`